# Create XML using Linq to XML and arrays

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am using Linq To XML to create XML that is sent to a third party. I am having difficulty understanding how to create the XML using Linq when part of information I want to send in the XML will be dynamic.

The dynamic part of the XML is held as a string[,] array. This multi dimensional array holds 2 values.

I can 'build' the dynamic XML up using a stringbuilder and store the values that were in the array into a string variable but when I try to include this variable into Linq the variable is HTMLEncoded rather than included as proper XML.

How would I go about adding in my dynamically built string to the XML being built up by Linq?

For Example:

```
//string below contains values passed into my class
```

string[,] AccessoriesSelected;

```
//I loop through the above array and build up my 'Tag' and store in string called AccessoriesXML


//simple linq to xml example with my AccessoriesXML value passed into it
XDocument RequestDoc = new XDocument(
 new XElement("MainTag",
 new XAttribute("Innervalue", "2")
 ),
AccessoriesXML);
```

'Tag' is an optional extra, it might appear in my XML multiple times or it might not - it's dependant on a user checking some checkboxes.

Right now when I run my code I see this:

```
<MainTag> blah blah </MainTag>
&lt ;Tag&gt ;&lt ;InnerTag&gt ; option1="valuefromarray0" option2="valuefromarray1" /&gt ;&lt ;Tag/&gt ;
```

I want to return something this:

```
<MainTag> blah blah </MainTag>
<Tag><InnerTag option1="valuefromarray0" option2="valuefromarray1" /></Tag>
<Tag><InnerTag option1="valuefromarray0" option2="valuefromarray1" /></Tag>
```

Any thoughts or suggestions? I can get this working using XmlDocument but I would like to get this working with Linq if it is possible.

Thanks for your help,
Rich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building XElements with the ("name", "value") constructor will use the value text as literal text - and escape it if necessary to achieve that.

If you want to create the XElement programatically from a snippet of XML text that you want to actually be interpreted as XML, you should use `XElement.Load()`.  This will parse the string as actual XML, instead of trying to assign the text of the string as an escaped literal value.

Try this:

```
XDocument RequestDoc = new XDocument(
 new XElement("MainTag",
 new XAttribute("Innervalue", "2")
 ),
 XElement.Load(new StringReader(AccessoriesXML)));
```

Comment: That was it! I won't embarrass myself by saying how long I have been messing around with this to get it working haha! thanks :)

Comment: Why have you used `StringReader`? Is it wrong to simply do this? `XElement.Load(AccessoriesXML)`